8bit Image to 24bit Image
I make a gif file, which would be 8bit, right? Now I want to extract the frames as 24bit images and/or convert the extracted images to 24bit. How do I do that?

I use Shutter Encoder to make the gifs for the first part. Now what software can do the second part?

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. if it's an animated GIF file, then GIFs don't support RGB colour (8 bits per channel=24bit).  You'll need to use another format like APNG, or use a video format instead. Check your software user manual to see what formats it supports when exporting. Note also that questions about video editing/software are off-topic here. Sorry about that.  Try Video Production Stack Exchange instead.

It is confusing what you want. 1. Do you want single frames? 2. Do you want all the frames exported as a movie? 3. Do you want to export all single frames as a sequence? 4. Do you have the source files? 5. It will be a lot better to export the original project to img sequence.

I want all frames extracted from my gifs. And yes, I have the videos where I made the gifs from.

No. Again. It is still not clear why you are using GIF as an intermediate format. If you want all frames to be 24 bits, export them from the original videos, not from the GIF. You are corrupting, degrading, and grinding them... Why?

If you have a GIF, and you convert to another format which supports RGB (24bit) colours, then you gain absolutely nothing from doing this.  The GIF format itself has already mangled the colours. It's too late to fix. There can be no return to the original RGB colour data.  If you want to do this take Rafael's advice. Use software which can output a PNG sequence in RBG colour directly from your original video file. Forget GIFs entirely.

use shutter encoder to make your gif and then use it on the same video to export JPEG images.

One option on PC is to take VirtualDub2 which is free. https://sourceforge.net/projects/vdfiltermod/files/

Open the Gif.

Export to whatever you need. Probably an image sequence.



If you choose PNG it will be saved as 24-bit PNG files.

However, it is a better option to export your sequence directly from your source application.

You mean the video?

I mean that you need to define what final format you need. If you need a video export a video. If it is an animated gif export an animated gif. It seems that you are using gif as a "middle file" but by doing so you are "degradating" your file.


I make a gif file, which would be 8bit, right?

No, it would be an indexed file that has used a 8 bit slice of 24 bit color space. This is not same as being 8 bits, its not measuring same thing.

Now I want to extract the frames as 24bit images and/or convert the extracted images to 24bit. How do I do that?

Well, either the answer is you can not or just save in any 24- bit format. Technically the later is correct, but feels like trolling.
Basically theres no way to get the colors back as they were in the file before the gif. But since obviously you can just write the gif out into the 24 bit format unchanged from what it was in the gif, thats what happens whenever you view your file. But this does not accomplish anythng, nor does it solve any meaningful problem.
PS: there is a high likelyhood that this is a XY problem
